# How to make XML-RPC endpoints more secure?

Tags: teamcity, xml-rpc, endpoints

TeamCity exposes unsecured XML-RPC entry points, Can someone please guide how to make them secure.

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer from Teamcity support team.

"As XML-RPC uses the HTTP protocol so the easiest option would be to set up TeamCity to use SSL. You can find the documentation for the procedure here:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Using+HTTPS+to+access+TeamCity+server"

Hope it will be helpful for some one.